# When I open a new activity from an intent (button) from my previous activity, the button remains on the new activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an issue of a button remaining on the new activity, from which the button on the previous activity had launched.

Example: Activity A contains Button (B1). On clickevent of B1 takes you to Activity B. When B1 is clicked it successfully takes you to Activity B.

Extra Information: Activity A and Activity B are both WebViews and are on relative layout.

Issue: There is no Button on Activity B, but when I open my app on my phone, B1 appears.

Any help will be appreciated I am very new to coding!

This is Class A

```
WebView myBrowser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drugs);

    myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
    myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/drugs.html");
    myBrowser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    Button btndrugslaw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.drugslaw);

    btndrugslaw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intentdruglaw = new Intent(Drugs.this, DrugLaw.class);
            startActivity(intentdruglaw);
        }
    });

}
```

This is Activity A

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="kyr.com.knowyourrights.Drugs"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/mybrowser"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >

</WebView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Take me to the law"
    android:id="@+id/drugslaw"
    android:layout_below="@id/mybrowser"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

This is Class B

```
WebView myBrowser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_parking_fine);

    myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
    myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/druglaw.html");
    myBrowser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
}
```

This is Activity B

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="kyr.com.knowyourrights.DrugLaw"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/mybrowser1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</WebView>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Provide code of both Activity A and B

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: @Viverson : Add code please.!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you show some code? Please take a look at [mcve], a page that helps writing questions.

Comment: @Viverson : I guess may be you are using same layout for noth activities..!!

Comment: @AndiGeeky yeah U are right, be he said that he is using webview, thats why we need to check code first

Comment: @Darshak : Yeah sure..!!

Comment: Hey guys, for my first post thanks for the instant replies!

Comment: Both xml layout have buttons, thats why it showing to you.

Comment: @Darshak Sorry i copied in the wrong code!

Comment: @roadrunner66 : Thanks for linking guide!

Comment: Hey guys, was wondering if someone could still help me out with this. I pasted in the code that I am using and still having the same issue